# How to compactly present several graphs

Tags: web-app, dashboard, graphs

I'd like to present my user with several pre-defined different graphs (of different data), while not taking up too much space.

My initial try was to aim to use small tabs, but hallway testing found opposition. What would be the recommended way to present this efficiently?

I tried a dropdown, but I don't like the way it feels (very "computery").
See screenshots below for tab and dropdown examples (note, styling is not done yet)

[image: Tabs]
[image: Dropdown]

Answer (score 1):

I'd treat the entire graphs as buttons, something like this:

[image]

this way, you provide some degree of information to the user and make your element the trigger of an action, saving space as well as steps in your process. Of course you would need to test, but I think this approach will greatly reduce any cognitive dissonance by adding a quick eye scan reference

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use the tab format you preferred - but on top of the graph not below. I certainly don't go much on the drop down as I think this hides the options and graphs available (as you have to click to view them).

What I would suggest is that if you have a live system then try to AB test it and see which gives the most number of different graph views.

https://www.optimizely.com/ab-testing/

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/24/the-ultimate-guide-to-a-b-testing/

Comment: It's a product under development, so we don't have any visitors to AB test with :)

Comment: Fair enough, nothing you can do about that :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called "micro charts". These type of controls are both interactive and informational.  I suggest you google it up.

Comment: If you mean sparkling, than those are quite different than what I am trying to do. I'm looking for information rich charts, displayed in a compact way :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can't simply show all of them since that would clutter up the place